# Set value of a child in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database having a child - "hello" having value - "one". Now, using the javascript, I need to set the value of "hello" as "two". Thanks in advance. Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a really basic question. The answer can be easily found in the firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup). I'd strongly recommend you to always keep an eye on the docs when learning how to use firebase, because it is a great source and it covers a lot of use cases.

First, initialize your app

```
var config = {
      apiKey: '<your-api-key>',
      authDomain: '<your-auth-domain>',
      databaseURL: '<your-database-url>',
      storageBucket: '<your-storage-bucket>'
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Then, in your javascript, make sure you have a valid reference to your database and then run either one of these lines

```
firebase.database().ref("hello").set('two');
```

or

```
firebase.database().ref().update({hello: 'two'});
```